# Is this the correct way to start a service with alarm manager in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

This is my code for an alarm manager. I want to register for the system alarm service based on a result from the database.

```
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    SQLiteDatabase database = new TaskDatabaseManager(context)
            .getWritableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd",
            Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
    String today = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    Cursor c = database
            .rawQuery("Select " + TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_TIMES2
                    + " from " + TaskDatabaseManager.DATABASE_TABLE
                    + " where " + TaskDatabaseManager.TASK_DATE + "= ?",
                    new String[] { today });
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.getCount() != 0) {
        do {
            try {
                long mili = dateFormat2.parse(c.getString(0)).getTime();
                PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                        intent1, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mili, p);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Next Next",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

Below is my service class.  Right now, to test this part of the code, I am using Toast.

```
                     public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
```

Basically, I want to start a service which will show a particular notification at a particular time that is stored in the database. The time is entered by the user and based on that, it will create a notification at that time. I am new to Android.

Comment: Yes.  @Squonk but not working

Comment: OK...so add some logging and check logcat.

Comment: @Squonk nothing in log cat

Comment: What I meant is if you add `Log` calls to your code you can trace how far it gets.

Comment: @Squonk I know how to use log cat.. :)  And nothing is logged in log cat I added log statement in both broadcast receiver and service class. But nothing is in log cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Correct Way to do this is

```
    Intent otherIntent = new Intent();
    otherIntent.setClass(this, YourService.class);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), otherIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, yourTimeInMillis(), intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest have you written

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".NotificationService " />
```

check the c.getCount() whether it is nonzero or not.